# Perl: What is this + doing here? (print plus)

Tags: perl

I came across [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=385338) which prints the last line of a text file:

```
use File::ReadBackwards;
print +( 
        File::ReadBackwards->new('file.txt') || die $! 
       )->readline();
```

What is the `+` for in `print +(` ?

It doesn't help that Google search ignores symbols such as "+" or "+(" in queries...

Comment: To summarize the dup, without the plus sign, it parses as `(print(...))->readline()`. i.e it tries to call `readline` on the result of `print`.

Comment: Thanks @that other guy for the link, and @ Silvio Mayolo for the summary. It all makes sense now.

Comment: The following code also works, and some may find it clearer: `print ((File::ReadBackwards->new('file.txt') || die $!)->readline());`

Comment: This code should be two or even three separate statements: `my $fh = File::ReadBackwards->new('file.txt') or die $!`, `my $line = <$fh>` and `print $line`. (The last two may be combined as `print scalar <$fh>`.)  It's a false economy to reduce code to the point of obfuscation.

Comment: *"It doesn't help that Google search ignores symbols such as "+" or "+(" in queries..."* The plus sign is a Google search metacharacter. You need to put it inside quotes to make it part of the search string: `perl "print +("` works fine.